# How to get access to global variable in template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to create global object with settings which I need to get from REST API. I need to make one request to REST API and get settings and after that I want to get access to these settings from any controllers and from any templates. What can you advice, what is the best practice for that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Concept

Good practice would be to use [initializers](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/). They allow injection of any data to routes, controllers or any other kind of object.

Lets take an example **(** *example from Ember.js official site* **)**

**1 .** *You have an `Application` and you have a `logger` service like this -*

```
App = Ember.Application.extend();

App.Logger = Ember.Object.extend({
  log: function(m) {
    console.log(m);
  }
});
```

**2 .** *Now you want to have this function `log` to available on all `routes` like this -*

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function(){
    // The logger property is injected into all routes
    this.logger.log('Entered the index route!');
  }
});
```

**3.** *Tell ember to inject an object named `Logger` to all routes. Use `initializer` Like this*

```
//I want to inject something
Ember.Application.initializer({

  //this dependency name is logger
  name: 'logger',

  //whenever ember runs
  initialize: function(container, application) {

    //register my logger object under a name
    application.register('logger:main', App.Logger);

    //and use this service 'logger' in all 'routes'
    application.inject('route', 'logger', 'logger:main');
  }
});
```

With this you can have your application level data / code available in all routes and controller.

Once you get your data in controller you can use it in templates pretty easily.

### How to make API call with initializers ??

Initializer can be used to run after some other services has been resolved. Like in our case `store`. `store` is the object we need to make API call to server in good way (We can use `$.getJSON()` or anything else no issues)

*Tell the initializers to run after `store` loaded*

```
//I want to inject something but only after store resolved
Ember.Application.initializer({

  //this dependency name is logger
  name: 'logger',

  //wait for store object to be loaded, we need it to make API call
  after : 'store',


  //whenever ember runs
  initialize: function(container, application) {

      //grab the store object from container
      var store = container.lookup('store:main');

      //now you the store make that API call
      self.store.find('user',{current:true}).then(function(data){

            //we have the data we can inject it
            data = data.get('firstObject');
            container.lookup('controller:base').set('user', data);

            //user lookup success
            console.log("We have found an user. Yeah ember rocks.");

       });
   }

});
```

Comment: Initializers are pretty cool - agreed. Not sure if they are the best tool for injecting **data** though...

Comment: @KalmanHazins Yes, we can tell injection to run after `store` has been resolved. Then use `store` to make API call and inject data everywhere :)

Comment: definitely could be done; I just wasn't sure if it's the best place for it. We need someone like @Oren to decide on this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

The settings object you are describing should probably live inside `ApplicationRoute`'s `model` hook. You can then retrieve it in all your other models by saying `modelFor('application')` (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor)). There is also a `needs` API (see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)) that lets you share stuff between controllers in the application.